# Bootstrap 3 - How to properly align columns in smaller resolutions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a **col-sm-6** with Bootstrap 3 to create a row of 2 columns in smaller resolutions. Some columns are longer than others. Since I have 4 column in a row, here is an example of what I want:

[image]

It works fine when all rows have an (approximate) equel length.

However, let's say that my first column contains more text and is longer then the other columns, this is what I get:

[image]

Does anyone know a solution for this issue? I also placed a working example here:

http://www.bootply.com/SD1Cc4qmrS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue! Here's the preferred solution from the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

And here it is applied to your example. http://www.bootply.com/6nJK9XpSge

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you! Didn't know that it is possible in Bootstrap to reset columns like this with clearfix.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="border">Col 1: Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="border">Col 2: Short text</div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="border">Col 3: Short text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="border">Col 4: Short text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```